# Intellij IDEA sstrange packges inside maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am currently creating an empty spring boot project, and every time I make it these strange empty packages appears in the hierarchy of packages view scope . !

my package is `com.dmlabs.hourly` and I have nothing to do with those other empty packages

I don't know where to post this to got help, but for the dev community, can anyone solve this?

[image]

Comment: Is that because you selecting **Packages** from the drop-down menu on the upper right corner? Perhaps select **Projects**.
I'm using Intellij IDEA Community Edition on Windows 10, I didn't see the problem that you faced

Comment: I usually use packages view to focus more on code not files, but when I select files view it's not listing those empty packages as you said, this is not the  solution I wanted